# Using SQLite Json Functions I want to retrieve a value base on the value near it

Tags: json, sqlite, select, where-clause

Lets say I have this Json and I would like to retrieve all the age values where the name equals Chris in the Array key.

```
{
    "Array": [
        {
            "age": "65",
            "name": "Chris"
        },
        {
            "age": "20",
            "name": "Mark"
        },
        {
            "age": "23",
            "name": "Chris"
        }
    ]
}
```

That Json is present in the Json column inside my database.
by that I would like to retrieve one age column the has the age 65 and 23 because they both named Chris.

Comment: You have to show the code you used to obtain a json you posted. There are a lot of languages, we even don't know what you use

Comment: As I said I wanted to use sqlite to retrieve those values from my sqlite database... Already I got the answer that I need:) thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) table-valued function to extract all the names and ages from the json array of each row of the table and [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex) function to filter the rows for `'Chris'` and get his age:

```
SELECT json_extract(j.value, '$.name') name, 
       json_extract(j.value, '$.age') age
FROM tablename t JOIN json_each(t.col, "$.Array") j
WHERE json_extract(j.value, '$.name') = 'Chris';
```

Change `col` to the name of the json column.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b700acae280b0e202f4cac1fb3dcb98e).